# Failure while deploying EAR file on Jboss Wildfly

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I've got an EAR file which contains two wars and multiple jars. I'm using maven-ear-plugin to generate this file.

All jars are added in lib. There are few local jars and I'm adding them directly under EAR file. I've 2 local jars with a different name but contains the same package say abc.jar and xyz.jar

When I deploy this file on server I get following error:

```
"{\"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.mbean.service.publish:service=StreamReceiverStartup.start\" => \"org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.mbean.service.publish:service=StreamReceiverStartup.start: WFLYSAR0001: Failed to execute legacy service start() method
    Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: <package_name>/<class_file>
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <class_file> from [Module \\\"deployment.<ear_file_name>.ear.<jar_name>.jar:main\\\" from Service Module Loader]\"}}"
```

It's trying to detect  from abc.jar instead xyz.jar which contains .

How to resolve this conflict? I tried removing one of the jar files. It results in the same exception but for a different class file, so I cannot discard any of these jars.

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed by removing jars from application.xml